How to customize error messages for invalid authentication in Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security 6?
I am developing a Spring Boot 3 application with Spring Security 6, and I need to customize the error messages for invalid API keys. When an invalid API key is provided, I want the error message "Invalid API Key" to be returned instead of the default "Full authentication is required to access this resource."
Here are the classes I have implemented so far:
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        data.put("error", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

        response.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
    }
}

@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ApiKeyAuthFilter.class.getName());
    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER = "X-API-KEY";
    private static final String VALID_API_KEY = "valid-api-key";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, ApiKeyAuthenticationException {
        String apiKey = request.getHeader(API_KEY_HEADER);
        LOGGER.info("API Key received: " + apiKey);

        if (VALID_API_KEY.equals(apiKey)) {
            UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("apiKeyUser")
                    .password("")
                    .authorities(Collections.emptyList())
                    .build();

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            LOGGER.info("Authentication set in security context");
        } else {
            throw new ApiKeyAuthenticationException("Invalid API Key");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.customAuthenticationEntryPoint = customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                        exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint));

        return http.build();
    }
}

Despite these implementations, the error message returned is still the default "Full authentication is required to access this resource."
How can I ensure that the custom error message "Invalid API Key" is returned when an invalid API key is provided?
Thank you for your help!
Update:
I found that by catching the AuthenticationException directly in the ApiKeyAuthFilter class, I can influence the response text. However, I don't think this is an optimal solution. Here is the updated ApiKeyAuthFilter class:
@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ApiKeyAuthFilter.class.getName());
    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER = "X-API-KEY";
    private static final String VALID_API_KEY = "valid-api-key";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, ApiKeyAuthenticationException {
        String apiKey = request.getHeader(API_KEY_HEADER);
        LOGGER.info("API Key received: " + apiKey);

        try {

            if (VALID_API_KEY.equals(apiKey)) {
                UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("apiKeyUser")
                        .password("")
                        .authorities(Collections.emptyList())
                        .build();

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                LOGGER.info("Authentication set in security context");
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                throw new ApiKeyAuthenticationException("Invalid API Key");
            }

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"" + e.getMessage() + "\", \"error\": \"UNAUTHORIZED\"}");
        }

    }
}



why would you want to aid malicious actors in their attempts to hack your application by providing them with information of what has gone wrong.

Security mentions often depend on the specific case, as in this instance. Since this is an internal application, I don't see any problem with returning meaningful error messages. This makes troubleshooting easier and helps all colleagues involved in the process to quickly find the cause in case of an error.

You dont, but the community as a whole sees otherwise as this is an internal service is not a valid argument as security should be provided in layers. If its an internal service, then a valid argument would be, why even bother with security at all. Developers have access to logs. They can read them.

Thank you for your feedback, but I have a different point of view. I consider log file information to be more sensitive than providing an appropriate error message for an invalid API key.

well as mentioned, the community as a whole sees otherwise, and this is also reflected in the answer i have given below in how to implement it. And i strongly recommend you to revise your point of view to align with the community. Good luck

Your question is a lot harder to answer then you think because this is not best practice to provide helpful information in security related responses as this will aid people with malicious intents.
if you read the source code:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/edd6182fb00e6c4bc5cf8dde5f8e4df27bbcb42f/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L172
you can see that if the exception is an instance of a AuthenticationException or a AccessDeniedException spring security will redirect the user and try to start an authentication process. Here is the message you are seeing hardcoded.
If its none of them it will just rethrow the exception.
If the user is anonymous (someone that is not logged in) trying to access something they are not allowed, spring will start an authentication process and you can customize that by providing your own implementation of the AuthenticationEntryPoint interface.
On the other hand if the user is known (someone that is logged) and is trying to access something they are not allowed you can provide your own implementation of the AccessDeniedHandler interface.
So doing what you want is not as simple as you think as it is not best practice.
